# Defining function/method param as pointer and passing without reference

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

I have a question regarding pointers/references, I couldn't find much information about, so, having this method declaration (C++):

```
void RequestParser::parseRequest(const char * request)
```

When I want to use this method, I can call it like this:

```
requestParser.parseRequest(buffer);
```

So, going back to the definition the parameter expects a pointer (const char * request), why am I allowed to pass buffer without the reference, this way:

```
requestParser.parseRequest(&buffer);
```

This should be the correct way, right? Maybe there is some magic going on behind the scenes, like this:

```
void RequestParser::parseRequest(const char request[])
```

I know that you can't pass array as value (at least char arrays), so this is only syntactic sugar for this:

```
void RequestParser::parseRequest(const char * request)
```

What am I misunderstanding?

Comment: What's the type of `buffer`?

Comment: It's a char array, declared as:         char buffer[2048] = {'\0'}; BTW why am I getting downvoted?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is array decaying?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-decaying)

Comment: The ampersand, `&`, has several meanings. In types, it indicates a reference type; as a unary operator applied to one expression, it is the "address-of" operator and gives you a pointer (not a reference); as a binary operator it is "bitwise and".

Answer (score 3):

When you pass an array like `buffer` to `parseRequest`, [array-to-pointer decay](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/array#Array-to-pointer_decay) occurs,

> There is an implicit conversion from lvalues and rvalues of array type to rvalues of pointer type: it constructs a pointer to the first element of an array. This conversion is used whenever arrays appear in context where arrays are not expected, but pointers are:

So you're passing the pointer to the 1st element of the array in fact, it's of type `char *` (and could convert to `const char*`).

On the other hand, you can't pass `&buffer`, which is taking the address of the array and returns the pointer to the array (i.e. `char (*)[2048]`), it doesn't match the parameter type `const char*`.

Comment: So I can't pass &buffer because it is already passing the reference to that variable?

Comment: @redigaffi It has nothing to do with referece, `&buffer` returns a pointer to the array, whose type is `char (*)[]`.